# Unable to Test Async Actions in Redux

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, redux

I was trying to test one of my function that has dispatch calls for my application in redux.
The test is using mocha, phantomjs. I am using nock to make http calls.

My test is:

```
import React from 'react/addons';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import nock from 'nock'
import expect from 'expect'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import {RECEIVE_DATA1,RECEIVE_DATA2,RECEIVE_DATA3,fetchAllData} from '../../src/actions/allActions'


const middlewares = [ thunk ];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);


  describe('async actions', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
      nock.cleanAll()
    })

    it('creates fetchAllDataAction call', (done) => {
      const requesting = false;
      nock('http://localhost:7788/')
        .get('/data/Data1')
        .reply(200,{ objects: { name: 'Test1'} } )
        .get('/Data2')
        .reply(200,{ objects: { name: 'Test2'} })
        .get('/Data3')
        .reply(200,{ objects: { name: 'Test3'} });

      const expectedActions = [
        { type: RECEIVE_DATA1 , objects: { name: 'Test1'}},
        { type: RECEIVE_DATA2 , objects: { name: 'Test2'}},
        { type: RECEIVE_DATA3 , objects: { name: 'Test3'} },
        { type: REQUEST_DATA3 , requesting},
      ]

      const store_mock = mockStore({},expectedActions,done)
      return store_mock.dispatch(fetchAllData())
        .then(() => {
          const actions = store.getActions()
          expect(actions).toEqual(expectedActions)
          done()
        })
    })
  })
```

I am trying to test this action:

```
export function fetchAllData(){
  return dispatch => {
    return $.getJSON(`${SERVER_ROOT}/data/Data1`)
     .then(json => {
     dispatch(receiveData1(json));
     $.getJSON(`${SERVER_ROOT}/Data2`)
      .then(json => {
        dispatch(receiveData2(json));
        $.getJSON(`${SERVER_ROOT}/Data3`)
          .then(json => {
            dispatch(receiveData3(json));
            dispatch(requestData3(false));
          });
      });
  });
 }
}

function receiveData1(data){
 return { type: RECEIVE_DATA1,
          data: data
        }
}

function receiveData2(data){
 return { type: RECEIVE_DATA2,
          data
        }
}

function receiveData3(data){
 return { type: RECEIVE_DATA3,
          data
        }
 }

function requestData3(state){
 return { type: REQUEST_DATA3,
          state
        }
}
```

I get following error: 
timeout of 2000ms exceeded.Ensure the done() call back is being called in this test.

I am assuming that this could be because of the failure of dispatch call.
so i changed my call to

```
   store_mock.dispatch(fetchAllData())
        .then(() => { // return of async actions
          expect(store_mock.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
        })
        .then(done) 
        .catch(done)
```

I got this error: undefined is not a constructor (near '....catch(done); ...')

I am not sure what wrong I am doing.I am referring to http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html Async Action Creators tutorial.

I am very new to front end testing.It would be great if someone can help me out on this.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `done` both from `it`'s arguments and from the end of returned promise. When you're testing promises you should simply return a promise and do not do any `done()` callback

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return a promise from `it` block in mocha tests. That will allow you to avoid adding unnecessary `then` and `catch` blocks.

Also it might be much easier to test async action creators with [redux-actions-assertions](https://github.com/redux-things/redux-actions-assertions)

Then it will be simply:

```
it('creates fetchAllDataAction call', () => {
  const requesting = false;
  nock('http://localhost:7788/')
    .get('/data/Data1')
    .reply(200,{ objects: { name: 'Test1'} } )
    .get('/Data2')
    .reply(200,{ objects: { name: 'Test2'} })
    .get('/Data3')
    .reply(200,{ objects: { name: 'Test3'} });

  const expectedActions = [
    { type: RECEIVE_DATA1 , objects: { name: 'Test1'}},
    { type: RECEIVE_DATA2 , objects: { name: 'Test2'}},
    { type: RECEIVE_DATA3 , objects: { name: 'Test3'} },
    { type: REQUEST_DATA3 , requesting},
  ]

  return expect(fetchAllData()).toDispatchActions(expectedActions)
})
```

Or even:

```
it('creates fetchAllDataAction call', () => {
  const requesting = false;
  const response1 = { objects: { name: 'Test1'}};
  const response2 = { objects: { name: 'Test2'}};
  const response3 = { objects: { name: 'Test3'}};

  nock('http://localhost:7788/')
    .get('/data/Data1')
    .reply(200, response1)
    .get('/Data2')
    .reply(200, response2)
    .get('/Data3')
    .reply(200, response3);

  return expect(fetchAllData()).toDispatchActions([
    receiveData1(response1),
    receiveData2(response2),
    receiveData3(response3),
    requestData3(requesting)
  ])
})
```